# Routing issue laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Hi guys i am not able to see what am doing wrong even after doing research. Please assist. i am getting a NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: I am trying to access the getShow method or rather the stove.show route

```
 public function getIndex()
    {
    $stoves = Stove::all();

    return view('stoves.index');
     }

     public function anyData()
{
$stoves = Stove::select(['id','stoveno', 'refno', 'manufactuerdate', 'created_at']);
    return Datatables::of($stoves)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($stoves) {
            return '<a href="stove/show/'.$stoves->stoveno.'" class="btn btn-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> History</a>';
        })

        ->make(true);
}

public function addData()
{
    //
    return view('stoves.new');
}

public function store(AddStove $request)
{
   Stove::create($request->all());

       return redirect('stove');
}

public function getShow($id)
{
    $stove = Stove::findorFail('$id');
    return view('stoves.view', compact('stove'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

My route looks like

```
 Route::controller('stove', 'StoveController', [
'anyData'  => 'stove.data',
'getShow'  => 'stove.show',
'getIndex' => 'stove',
]);
Route::get('newstove', 'StoveController@addData');
Route::post('newstove', 'StoveController@store');
```

my view folder contains index.blade, new.blade and finally view.blade

Thanks i appreciate

Comment: how about give "getIndex" a different name?, also can you paste exception stack?

Comment: what url are you trying to reach, what http method are you using, etc ...

Comment: I am trying to reach the stoveController@show. NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269:
Controller method not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Route::get('getShow/{id}','stoveController@getShow');
```

If problem exist, remove this line

```
'getShow'  => 'stove.show',
```